# does anyone know the exactly term about these two type of selection interaction?

Tags: navigation, design-patterns

[image]

Image A is a highlight box moving alone with the icon, focal point with move with the icon. Dose anyone know about this kind of menu type or selection technique's name?

Image B is like carousel menu, focal point is fixed, all icon circulate through the middle highlight box.

Comment: I don't think there's a name for it. It's just a variation of the carousel pattern, since *the carousel does not necessary has a fixed point*. Check the examples on http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Carousel

Answer (score 1):

**A. Page or Navigation Flow indicator.**

Much like a bread crumb or page indicator it shows a fixed number of steps and the user's current position. Its name can vary with what it's indication.

**B. Carousel or picker.**

Like @L. Mller said it is one of the variation of carousels. Typically the user's selection or position is in a fixed point or frame. The box can be considered as a visual treatment of the fixed point thereby emphasising the selection. This is not a mandatory visual treatment - and others treatments can work just as well, such as underlines, arrows, dots, spotlight, etc ...